# How to capture videos with react-native-camera module?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I can capture pictures with this module without any problem, but when I try to record video, I can't seem to find where the recorded video is (or maybe no video was even recorded at all). Here is my `CameraScreen`:

```
import Camera from 'react-native-camera';

const { CaptureMode, CaptureTarget } = Camera.constants;
const { video: captureModeVideo, still: captureModePhoto } = CaptureMode;

class CameraScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            captureMode: captureModePhoto,
            isRecording: false
        };

        this.onCapture = this.onCapture.bind(this);
        this.onSwitchCaptureMode = this.onSwitchCameraMode.bind(this);
    }

    onCapture() {
        const { captureMode, isRecording } = this.state;

        if (isRecording) {
            this._camera.stopCapture();
            this.setState({ isRecording: false });
            return;
        }

        if (captureMode === captureModeVideo) {
            this.setState({ isRecording: true });
        }

        this._camera.capture({ mode: captureMode })
            .then((result) => console.log(result))
            .catch((error) => console.log(error));
    }

    onSwitchCaptureMode() {
        if (this.state.captureMode === captureModeVideo) {
            this.setState({ captureMode: captureModePhoto });
        } else {
            this.setState({ captureMode: captureModeVideo });
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { captureMode } = this.state;

        return (
            <Camera
                ref={(ref) => this._camera = ref}
                style={{ flex: 1 }}
                captureMode={captureMode}
                captureTarget={CaptureTarget.disk}
            >
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onCapture}>
                    <Icon
                        name='camera-alt'
                        ...
                        ...
                    />
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onSwitchCaptureMode}>
                    <Icon
                        name='...'
                        ...
                        ...
                    />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </Camera>
        );
    }
}

export default CameraScreen;
```

When I'm taking photos, the `console.log(result)` statement logs the path of the photo without a problem, but when `captureMode === captureModePhoto`, I don't have any logs in my debugger, is there something I'm doing wrong? I omitted many stylings to make the code more understandable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a silly mistake

The code posted by me works absolutely fine, but I have to test it on a real device. A simulator supports taking images (it generates some image with a random background color), but doesn't support taking videos. Therefore, problem solved